# RuntimeException during start of intent

Tags: java, android

I am getting this exception at start of every screen ,irrespective of giving height.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #25: You must supply a layout_height attribute.

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove attribute parent="android:Theme" for the specified activity. your problem will solved. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837920/exception-in-android-xml) link of stackoverflow

If you're using the `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"` in your AndroidManifest.xml and then running your app on an Android 2.3 device or Android 2.2 device, then you will see that warning at startup. A possible solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830916/android-theme-holo-previous-version):

Answer (score 2):

Every view in your xml file must have a layout_height and layout_width attribute defined. If you look at the xml file on line 25, you should be missing that. I.e:

```
<LinearLayout layout_height="fill_parent" 
               layout_width="fill_parent"/>
```