# Exception in Android XML

Tags: android, layout

I get an exception every time I launch the application. Here is the stacktrace for the exception

```
10-01 14:49:35.321: WARN/WindowManager(61): Exception when adding starting window
10-01 14:49:35.321: WARN/WindowManager(61): java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #25: You must supply a layout_height attribute.
10-01 14:49:35.321: WARN/WindowManager(61):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:438)
10-01 14:49:35.321: WARN/WindowManager(61):     at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:3468)
10-01 14:49:35.321: WARN/WindowManager(61):     at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:3547)
10-01 14:49:35.321: WARN/WindowManager(61):     at android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(LinearLayout.java:1265)
10-01 14:49:35.321: WARN/WindowManager(61):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1191)
10-01 14:49:35.321: WARN/WindowManager(61):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:45)
10-01 14:49:35.321: WARN/WindowManager(61):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:620)
10-01 14:49:35.321: WARN/WindowManager(61):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
10-01 14:49:35.321: WARN/WindowManager(61):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
10-01 14:49:35.321: WARN/WindowManager(61):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
10-01 14:49:35.321: WARN/WindowManager(61):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2153)
10-01 14:49:35.321: WARN/WindowManager(61):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2207)
10-01 14:49:35.321: WARN/WindowManager(61):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:1395)
10-01 14:49:35.321: WARN/WindowManager(61):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.addStartingWindow(PhoneWindowManager.java:818)
10-01 14:49:35.321: WARN/WindowManager(61):     at com.android.server.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage(WindowManagerService.java:8794)
10-01 14:49:35.321: WARN/WindowManager(61):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-01 14:49:35.321: WARN/WindowManager(61):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-01 14:49:35.321: WARN/WindowManager(61):     at com.android.server.WindowManagerService$WMThread.run(WindowManagerService.java:531)
```

I am also posting the XML file I'm using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/arw_layout" android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/arw_logo" android:layout_width="30px"
        android:layout_height="40px" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/arw_left" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/arw_left"
            android:textSize="25sp" android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" android:gravity="center_vertical" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/arw_title" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:minEms="10"
            android:text="@string/arw_title" android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" android:gravity="center" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/arw_right" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/arw_right"
            android:textSize="25sp" android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" android:gravity="center_vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
      android:startColor="#FF493538"
      android:centerColor="#FF000000"
      android:endColor="#FF000000"
      android:angle="270" />
</shape>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
</LinearLayout>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="Gallery1">
        <attr name="android:galleryItemBackground" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <style name="WindowTitleBackground" parent="android:WindowTitleBackground">
            <item name="android:background">@drawable/gradient</item>
        </style>
    </resources>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="titletheme">
        <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/WindowTitleBackground
        </item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: I have tested your layout and I haven't any errors.

Comment: What is your SDK version in manifest? And what is SDK version of your phone/emulator?

Comment: Are you sure this is the layout file that is triggering that exception?

Comment: @Sergey: I haven't specified SDK version in the manifest, but my emulator/device use 2.1 SDK

Comment: @CommonsWare: this is the only layout file I'm using. My layout folder also contains main.xml but I don't use it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution. I added the parent attribute parent="android:Theme" to my custom style, titletheme and it solved the problem.

Thanks for your replies

Comment: Same problem only I was adding pairs of of `values/themes.xml` and `values-v11/themes.xml` and forgot the `values/themes.xml` in one of the projects and got the error on pre V11 devices.

Comment: Explanation is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830916/android-theme-holo-previous-version