# Android 2.3.x crashing on com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsResult.startResolutionForResult

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-location-services

I'm in middle of a big issue,

OS VERSION: Android 2.3.x
DEVICE: GT i9100 (samsung galaxy s II)
LOCATION API:  com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0

PROBLEM: app crash calling 
com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsResult.startResolutionForResult

```
com.google.android.gms.ui E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main   java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #25: You must supply a layout_height attribute.
```

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #25: You must supply a layout_height attribute.
                                                       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:543)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:3599)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.(ViewGroup.java:3678)
                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.(LinearLayout.java:1400)
                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1326)
                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:47)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:625)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2261)
                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2316)
                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:1478)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2165)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1672)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

please refer the following link, i've exactly same issue
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=215183

please help me to fix this

Thanks

Comment: The error message seems fairly strait-forward: _You must supply a layout_height attribute._  You likely have a view somewhere (line 25?) in your layout XML that does not have the layout_height attribute.  You will also need a layout_width attribute if that is not defined.  These are two attributes which all views require.

Comment: This is not my layout ...they are referring to android.location.gms.ui

Comment: Are you sure?  I don't see anything in the error message which reflects this.  What activity are you passing into `startResolutionForResult()`?

Comment: this is the exact issue ..com.google.android.gms.ui E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #25: You must supply a layout_height attribute.

Comment: @pathfinderelite  please refer link ...  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=215183

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check solution given in this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837920/exception-in-android-xml) by @frieza if it can help.

As suggested, aside from defining `layout_height` and `layout_width` attributes shown in the posted codes, you might need to also set parent attribute with `parent="android:Theme"`.

Hope that works for you too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... but where i've to specify theme? This crash happening in com.google.android.gms.ui, when i'm calling startResolutionForResult for location setting request