# "Must supply height attribute" error

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to resolve an Android error "You must supply a layout_height attribute."  In DDMS the error message is:

```
10-06 12:45:12.431: WARN/WindowManager(62): HistoryRecord{406287f8 com.learning.android.yamba/.TimelineActivity} failed creating starting window
10-06 12:45:12.431: WARN/WindowManager(62): java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #25: You must supply a layout_height attribute.
10-06 12:45:12.431: WARN/WindowManager(62):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:491)
10-06 12:45:12.431: WARN/WindowManager(62):     at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:3599)
10-06 12:45:12.431: WARN/WindowManager(62):     at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:3678)
```

My TimelineActivity xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" style="@style/activity">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@style/title"
       android:text="@string/titleTimeline" android:layout_gravity="center">
    </TextView>
    <ListView style="@style/editbox" android:id="@+id/listStatuses"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The referenced styles are as follows:

```
<style name="activity">
    <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background</item>
 </style>

<style name="title">
    <item name="android:textSize">25dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>

<style name="editbox">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:background">#609f</item>
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15dp</item>
 </style>
```

The window background is not visible through the list box although I have set the listbox background to transparent.  Not sure if the two are related.

Answer (score 1):

See here for a solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5728794

The problem is probably because you've used a custom theme in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. It's nothing to do with your layout.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a few months old, but I think I have an answer for you.

You create a dimension value within the style xml:

```
<dimen name="layoutheight_title">wrap_content</dimen> 
<dimen name="layoutwidth_title">fill_parent</dimen>
```

Then you reference the dimension value in your xml layouts as necessary.

```
android:layout_height="@dimen/layoutheight_title" 
android:layout_width="@dimen/layoutwidth_title"
```