# Android: Theme Holo previous version

Tags: java, android, styles, themes

I really like the 4.0 ICS Holo Light theme and would like to have it in my app to support <4.0 smartphones.

I found Android layoutlib.jar in platform folder but its 8mb!!! and I really don't have afford to increase my app with 8mb.
Any tip?

//Pew Labs
PS ive tried https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere but it doesnt support TabVIew which I use

Thanks!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It would be better not to use the Holo theme on unsupported devices. You can do a simple trick to make your app run the Holo theme on 3.x and up, and one of the built in themes on 2.3 and below, like so:

1. In your manifest, use this line for your activity's theme

   android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme"
2. In your res/values folder put a styles.xml file, containing

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
     <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black" />
   </resources>
   ```
3. Create a res/values-v11 folder, and a styles.xml file in that, containing:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
     <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo" />
   </resources>
   ```

This will make Android use the Holo theme if the app is running on a device that supports it (3.x and up, which is API level 11 and up, hence the "values-v11"). This is the best solution to make your app match the phone's user interface, and use the Holo theme only wherever it's supported.

Comment: I get error as - `error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 
 '@android:style/Theme.Holo'.` Should I be building this with 4.0? But I want to support as low as 2.1.

Comment: Build with 4.0, just make sure in your manifest you specify something like `<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="11" />`

Comment: if you still getting this error go to project propeties and select sdk target 14

Comment: @Nick thanks Nick this rocks! Also, this is the best solution when using Phonegap/Cordova to theme the native controls

Answer (score 4):

Check [ActionbarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/). It also provides a styled TabView. The samples directory provides a real good example for a TabView which works like a charm on Android 2.2.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Holo in Android 2.3< with this simple library : http://www.holoeverywhere.com/ 
Its called Holo everywhere and works fine in previous versions of android.
The Library is hosted on [Github](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere).

Comment: http://www.holoeverywhere.com/ does not link to a support library. It links to a blog showing good examples of apps using Holo themes.

Comment: Yes, but the blog links to its Library called "Holoeverywhere" on Github. https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere

Comment: I may be wrong but I don't think the site and library are by the same person. The site just links to the library.